# Jest moduleNameMapper ignores dot (\\.) and mocks what it shouldn't

Tags: webpack, jestjs

I have a TypeScript & Webpack project I'm configuring Jest for.

In some places I `import` files with `.svg` extension for Webpack to handle via its loaders, so I added to `jest.config.js` a `moduleNameMapper: {'\\.(svg)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js'}`.

However, when I run the tests it looks like it tries to replace `@ant-design/icons-svg` with the `fileMock.js` which it shouldn't because there's no dot (`.`) between `@ant-design/icons-` and `svg` (the dependency doesn't end with a `.svg`).

Running `jest` I get:

```
Configuration error:
Could not locate module @ant-design/icons-svg mapped as:
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Project\__mocks__\fileMock.js.
Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/\.(svg)$/": "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Project\__mocks__\fileMock.js"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}
```

If I create a `__mocks__/fileMock.js` file with `module.exports = 'MOCK';` this error goes away but the code under test breaks because `@ant-design/icons-svg` is replaced with `'MOCK'`.

How do I make it mock only files that end with `.svg`? The `\.(svg)$` regex should do that, but Jest seems to have a mind of its own.

---

## Additional info:

### babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
};
```

### jest.config.ts

```js
export default {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(svg)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    },
};
```

EDIT: I made a MCVE repository here: https://github.com/soryy708/jest-bug-mcve/

Comment: Opened a bug in Jest: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12005